# Require the user login facebook before he can use the App

Tags: java, android, facebook

I was going through the official guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/
I want that the user will must to login before he can use the app, but as you can see in the following picture, the user can just press the "X" and continue, I want that the login page will cover all the screen unlike this:(Please do not consider that Error is being displayed )

[image]

I want it to be like this, when user cannot really cancel the login and must login his account in order to use the app:

[image]

Comment: Forcing the user to connect with your app is a very good way to lose half the users during the first experience. There may be no other solutions for your app, but don't do this as a shortcut.

Comment: @Teovald My app is based on facebook, what do you mean by saying that there may be no other solutions for my app?

Comment: That there are cases where you legitimately need to log to a service to do anything with the app, for example a bank app.
But most of the time, it is not worth the users you will lose on that screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the login auth without the "X", the user's device must have the Facebook app installed.  Instead of a popup login auth, it will launch the Facebook app to do native SSO.  Even with that way, the user will still be able to cancel the login dialog and it will return back to your app.

The only way to prevent the user from moving forward in your app is to create a screen that only has the option to login from Facebook, and when you receive a valid access token, you can then launch the next activity in your app.

Comment: Wow, it is such a coincidence, Jesse, can I please refer you to my question? My question is similliar to other questions you have answered, but I tried to fix it from your instructions and no luck solving the issue, can you please help me?

Comment: Here, I really don't understand what's the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546809/configuring-app-to-facebook-error-app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login

Comment: The answer there is probably correct.  Your Android Hash Key is probably not correct, so enabling logging will help you identify the correct hash key, which you should then paste onto your app dashboard.  Also, make sure you are logged in to the native Facebook app, and that its updated to the latest version (just to make sure)

Answer (score 1):

You can create start screen with big button "Login with Facebook" and untill user successfully loged in he can't leave this screen.

Comment: Thank you.. can you give me an example of how to do it..? I want the login interface to look like facebook's api.

Comment: I mean then user presses this button, standard facebook dialog will appear (or facebook app is opened if installed).

Comment: Just like "Draw Something" do for example

Comment: Oh I understand now. But my friend who developing the same App managed to do the thing I'm talking about. like, the facebook login is an activity by itself, there's no way of canceling it untill you're logging. (And you don't have to press any button to create it), There's no "X" up there.

Comment: And what about login through facebook app? Do it still work with you friend solution?