# Configuring app to facebook Error : "App is misconfigured for Facebook login.."

Tags: java, android, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [App is misconfigured for Facebook login : Android Facebook integration issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382558/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-android-facebook-integration-issue)

I'm trying to integrate facebook into my app. When I press the login button and filling the email and password, I'm getting an error in the app saying : "

> App is misconfigured for Facebook login..

"
and then I have to press "Okay" button and it closes.

I have already filled the fields in my facebook app, here's a picture: [image]

Also, in the logcat when I press the "login" button (the button the I created that pops the facebook login). I see the following error:

> Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.AttributionIdProvider

Why the facebook login isn't working as well?

**EDIT:** After I press the Okay button, the logcat doesn't throw any error.

Comment: i am also facing the same problem, how do you solve it, please tell me...

Comment: @SivaK Just do what Srinivas suggested, it worked for me.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i dont know where to add the private static boolean ENABLE_LOG=true; in Util class and to get the key, can you please help me with a code....

Comment: When you go to the Util class in the facebook sdk library, you can see the the boolean Enable_LOG is set to false by default, simply set it to true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same error a few days ago, in my case it was due to android key mismatch.
here is how i fixed it if it may help u too,

Open Util.java in facebook sdk, 
set private static boolean ENABLE_LOG=true;
now run your app and enter the your email id and password,facebook sends back a signature if there's a key mismatch. you'll find this key(signature) in logcat. Just copy this key and paste it in app dashboard.
That should fix the problem.
Remember to set private static boolean ENABLE_LOG=true; back to false

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, that seems to be the solution because I think that the ENABLE_LOG instance is set to false. I can't test it right now since I have no device here, but I will have in 4 hours, I'll let you know if it worked, thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem and I solved it when I downloaded openssl-0.9.8e X64, before I used openssl-0.9.8k X64 and for some reason output was not valid. See this, I put my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382558/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-android-facebook-integration-issue/12553110#12553110

Comment: Hey sorry for the late comment, I've been really busy. well, I don't see any key after I press the "okay" button, actually nothing happens after I click on it. Here's the logcat. http://i.stack.imgur.com/qAGEQ.png

Comment: okay, then i would suggest you to keep all the complex implementations aside and keep the basic app and then try logging to check if its properly configured for SSO login.if that works, then there's some problem with your other piece of code.

Comment: alright, i've done that and still same problem. I'll post my codes in pastebins

Comment: nevermind, now I see the missing key and fixed it, it works, great thank you very much!!