# Android: Login using facebook API

Tags: android, facebook

I am using **Simple** example from the Facebook SDK just to get the user email, name, gender, facebookID to login to my server.

I am getting this Error:

**yourApp is misconfigured for Facebook login. Press Okay to leave application without facebook login**

This only occurs when i already have facebook app installed on my device. I tried uninstalling the facebook app, then i get correct details.

My application on facebook is configured as:

[image]

where am i doing wrong?

in place of **Class Name** i am giving the 1st Activity in my app, what exactly should i give here?

Thank You

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546809/configuring-app-to-facebook-error-app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login

Comment: Yeah i read that. But i am not getting anything in my logcat. Even after setting Enable_log = true

Comment: why dont you recalculate hash?

Comment: I am getting the same hash key

Comment: Are you using Facebook SDK 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even I had faced the same problem. It happens if you are using wrong version of openssl. I suggest you to use

**openssl_0.9.0e_win32** version and enable log (make it TRUE), later you get new key hash. Use the new one, problem will be solved! :)

Comment: I am using **openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip** which is mentioned everywhere

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo!! Dont use it, it has many bugs as I read in some blog.

Comment: use **openssl-0.9.8e_WIN32.zip** ??

Comment: I used and i got a new hash key. ill try it, but should i definitely give package name and class name?

Comment: yeah mention both of them and use the same version which I mentioned in my earlier reply.

Comment: What exactly is **Class Name**. Is it the 1st Activity in my application?? in docs its given class name which facebook opens. I didnt understand

Comment: First activity is enough. Might be your app splash screen activity name too. It will work. But give proper package name.

Comment: Hey! hope you can accept the answer by clicking (answer is useful).

Comment: Yeah i gave the SpalshScreenActivity as the Class Name and package name is also fine. And used new hashcode that came with **openssl-0.9.8e_WIN32**. but its the same error :((((

Comment: Then, there might be some other problem in permissions and other. Have you downloaded hackbook example?? Try to cross check with that! Also, try giving first activity name where you are using facebook API (not actually necessary).

Comment: I am following **Simple** example, not **hackbook**. My only puspose is to get user data, so **hackbook** seems complicated. But 1 thing is, when i uninstall facebook application on my device, it works fine.

Comment: oh yeah! That happened to me too. facebook application maintains all session data, I thought that was the problem and left it. But, it used to login (asks for sign in everytime you open application).